# Allure to generate reports for Android tests. How?

Tags: android, robotium, allure

Looking for good tool to generate reports for test results in Android.

I'm trying to connect [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) to generate reports for my integrated tests for Android. As test framework I'm using [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/).

Can't find any tutorials how to integrate this tools.

Is it possible? Or any suggestions about tools to generate reports?

Here is my build.gradle

```
configurations {
    agent
}

connectedCheck.doFirst {
    jvmArgs "-javaagent:${configurations.agent.singleFile}"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.2.1'
    agent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectjVersion}"
    androidTestCompile "ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-testng-adaptor:${allureVersion}"
}
```

and output:

```
1 error; aborting
:app:preDexDebugTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebugTest'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        /Users/vovs/Android/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/20.0.0/dx --dex --output /Users/vovs/Android/tmps/Robotium/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/test/debug/jaxb-api-2.2.7-5a4c4fa528666ece797bf985f28cd3e7059e62ce.jar /Users/vsvydenko/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.7/2f51c4bb4724ea408096ee9100ff2827e07e5b7c/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
  Error Code:
        1
  Output:

        trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.class":

        Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
        when not building a core library.
...
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't have Robotium Allure adaptor yet. You can implement it by yourself. We already have a Java API, so all you need is create a listener.

More information you can find here: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Creating-Allure-Adapter

Comment: I opened ticket for that: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/issues/862.